# Неисправность флешки?

Tags: файлы, файловая-система, flash-память

Флешка: Kingston - DT101 G2 - 8GB.

При подключении флешки (хоть в переднюю панель, хоть при подключении в саму материнку) проводник начинает сильно лагать. При этом подключенная флешка отображается так (без размера):
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При нажатии пкм на ней - проводник просто перестает отвечать.

Проверить на вирусы тоже не дает, при попытке выбрать эту флешку - антивирусники перестают отвечать. Та же ситуации с прогами для бэкапа - выбрать не получается, дается только в HDClone. Пробовал сделать бэкап на чистую флешку - стала такой же (перестала показывать размер и прочее).

В управлении дисками следующая ситуация:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Под линуксом (Ubuntu):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Какие есть варианты что это может быть и как можно исправить? Возможно ли восстановить данные?

Comment: Как минимум почитайте dmesg в линуксе